# WebView loads with white background in dark mode - flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

I am developing a flutter application that contains a WebView as well as the app supports dark mode. However, the issue is while loading webview content in dark mode the background color is white and as soon the webview loaded it turns to dark mode. Is there any way to start with dark mode if enabled?

Answer (score 2):

There are various solutions suggested online (and there is still no flutter webview patch for transparent background start-up).

A reliable workaround is wrapping the webview in an indexed Stack widget and showing a black loading card until the web view fires its page loaded event, then switching to the webview.